# Flexbox horizontally centered fixed-width rows in column

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I center my fixed width rows horizontally within a column oriented flexbox? `justify-content: center;` sounds like it should do the trick but it doesn't seem to work. Minimal example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ngr06e8w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `align-items: center;` in the css of `.col`

Here's the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ngr06e8w/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.col{margin:0 auto;}` insted of `justify-content: center;` and you are done.

```css
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.row1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}
.row2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="row1">
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
  </div>
</div>
```